# flutter to email, no line break for body

Tags: flutter

```
   final body = '123\n===\n444';
   final subject = 'bb123\n===\n444';

   final Uri emailLaunchUri = Uri(
      scheme: 'mailto',
      path: '*****@gmail.com',
      queryParameters: {
        'subject': subject,
        'body': body,
      },

  await launchUrl(emailLaunchUri);
```

For subject it works fine with line break, but for body it is just one line. I tried \r\n also not works [image: Above is subject, and bottom is body]

Comment: lol, cool bug. Try to use '''paragraph...'''. Using 3 ' with multiple lines of text.

Comment: Strange, for me it's the other way around, but it also makes sense, because I think a Subject can't have line breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try{
 String? encodeQueryParameters(Map<String, String> params) {
 return params.entries.map((MapEntry<String, String> e) =>
                
 '${Uri.encodeComponent(e.key)}=
  ${Uri.encodeComponent(e.value)}').join('&');
}
 final Uri emailLaunchUri = Uri(
 scheme: 'mailto',
 path: 'smith@example.com',
 query: encodeQueryParameters(<String, String>{
 'subject': subject,
 'body': body
  }),
   );

launchUrl(emailLaunchUri);

}catch(e){
  print(e);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).